# Win Iot and RS485 switch between sending and recieving

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-iot-core-10

After the good help I got with my last question I have to ask another one.

I'm currently trying to communicate with a Microcontroller over a UWP app.
I already got the code working which sends the data.

I took the same code which I used for a RS232 project I worked on parallel to this one.

Now the problem is that I can't recieve any data that is sent back to me.

Edit:

I found the solution to my problem...

I didn't recieve any answer because on my microcontroller I had a problem with the port I used to activate the sending function of my RS485 chip. Whenever I sent data it never switched to dending because my Pin had a problem. So I changed my Pin and now everything works well.

On the microcontroller I hace to switch between sending and recieving by sending a signal to the RS485 driver (MAX485).
Since I have the same driver on my IoT device I probably have to do the same here?
But since I find the documentary microsoft provides rather chaotic and not really clear (at least for me) I can't really find any way to achieve that...

Does anyone have an idea to achieve that?

For reference:
IoT Device: Raspberry Pi 3
µC: ATmega8 programmed with AVRco (because we use that at work...)

Comment: How did you connect the RS485 to your device?Did you use a USB to RS485 adapter? There is a similar topic about [Windows IoT and RS485](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83599e0c-6af7-4dfc-985a-d1455c834c51/windows-10-iot-rs485-uwp?forum=WindowsIoT) communication on MSDN.

Comment: I'm using a RS485 shield. I also saw the post but I couldn't find an answer there...

Comment: Did you use a USB to RS485 adapter to  connect the RS485 shield to Raspberry Pi 3? I think it is also possible to convert between RS485 and RS232 using simple interface converters.Have you read [User Guide of RS485 Shield for Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=158737)?Although it is with python on Linux, it is also helpful for your requirement.

Comment: Found a solution... Problem was with my µController and not with UWP...